# Visual Studio Unit Test fails in command prompt but passes in IDE

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

I have a Visual Studio project which passes my tests when I run them in the IDE.

When I try to run the same tests using VCTest.Console some of the tests fail even though they should pass.

I run the command prompt by running Deverloper Command Prompt for VS 2022 as admin and then navigate to my .dll test files and use the command: VSTest.Console file.dll